# Is there a way to find proximate words?

Tags: tanach, technology, text

I am looking to see if certain words in the tanach are used in proximity to other words. Other than looking a word up in my Even-Shoshan and reading through each instance and seeing if the other word is in the same pasuk, is there a way? When using Westlaw in the past, I know that there was a function that allowed searching "within" a distance so you could find all instances of "word 1" within x of "word 2". Is there such a resource for the tanach online?

If you have access to said technology, I am looking for instances of the word/root לחם within 3 words of any word with the root שבר. I know the words are in the same pasuk in 2 situations in Yechezkel (5:16 and 14:13) but I am looking for others.

Comment: Not online and only a partial solution, but Soncino has several software packages including various combinations of texts (Tanakh, talmud, Rashi, midrash, zohar, etc), and the one I have has a "X within N of Y" search.  But it doesn't do all variations of a root, just specific words.

Comment: Do you mean לחמ like bread or battle? and שבר like food or break?

Comment: Vayikra 26:26 ?

Comment: @DoubleAA The vayikra quote is great -- same construction as the yechezkel. I am actually trying to see if I can find some origin for a phrase "break bread" which might have at one point meant "sustenance or hope through bread".

Comment: @Dan Maybe try Bereishit 42:3 ? Note also the rabbinic term בציעת הפת

Comment: breishit has lisbor bar which is the right idea. All the sites which discuss the phrase's origin discuss 2 things: 1. that it is a "biblical phrase" though they have no citation, and 2. that it refers to the physical breaking/sharing of bread. I think that the similarity in roots shin-vet-reish somehow effected the English explanation.

Comment: @DoubleAA The 16 instances of b-tz-a in tanach don't seem to be connected to bread so I wonder where the rabbinic phrase originates.

Comment: The advanced options in the search of [responsa.co.il](http://www.responsa.co.il/) lets you do a search like that. However, the website seems to be down right now.

Comment: @ba thanks -- I just ran the search for the 2 roots ( לֶחֶם שָׁבָר) without nekudot, and I got only 2 hits on 5 word proximity.

Comment: A [regular expression](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html) ("regexp") is sort of like a mini computer program whose purpose is to do fancy searches through a corpus of text. I don't know if one can do the search you want using regexps, but maybe one can. First, try to find a copy of Tanach where the typist didn't press Enter at the end of each 80-character line. I don't know if such a copy exists. Then, open it in a program which supports regexps, such as gVim or MS Word. Finally, look online for a regexp for what you want. http://www.stackoverflow.com can help.

Answer (score 4):

I have Davka's Judaic Classics Torah Treasures it showed 5 results:
Vayikra 26,26; Yechezkel 4,16; Yechezkel 5,16; Yechezkel 14,13; and Tehilim 105,16.

Comment: thank you very much -- it looks like all 5 are sh-v-r and mateh-lechem which fits my request but doesn't clear up my etymological question. I just wonder why the responsa site didn't pick up 3 of these...

Comment: @Dan The best I found was Rashi on the Possuk in Vayikra who translates Mate as support, is that close to 'sustenance'?

Comment: mateh as support works as a complement to lechem but I was hoping to find a case where sh-v-r is the "sustenance" and is close to lechem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do such a search online.  **http://www.responsa.co.il**  Searches are Free, but full access requires a subscription.

To do this search, click "Advanced Search," change the "Proximity" to "3," and enter  "לחם שבר," with each word surrounded by * to search for all variations of those words.

Results for your example:

```
1.  ויקרא פרק כו
2.  ירמיהו פרק ד
3.  ירמיהו פרק נ
4.  יחזקאל פרק ד
5.  יחזקאל פרק ה
6.  יחזקאל פרק יד
7.  תהלים פרק קה
```